# Incorrect number of running calls with ProcessPoolExecutor in Python

Tags: python, concurrency, future, process-pool

In Python's `concurrent.futures` standard module, why does the number of running calls in a `ProcessPoolExecutor` is `max_workers + 1` instead of `max_workers` like in a `ThreadPoolExecutor`? This happens only when the number of submitted calls is strictly greater than the number of pool worker processes.

The following Python code snippet which submits 8 calls to 2 workers in a `ProcessPoolExecutor`:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time


def call():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(call) for _ in range(8)]
        time.sleep(5)

        for future in futures:
            print(future.running())
```

prints this (3 running calls; unexpected since there are 2 workers):

> True
>   True
>   True
>   False
>   False
>   False
>   False
>   False

while using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` prints this (2 running calls; expected):

> True
>   True
>   False
>   False
>   False
>   False
>   False
>   False

Comment: what is possible is that there's a race condition between the process launches (which take time) and the status, where with threads it's much faster. I mean: once the first one returned True, it can be False again. The snapshot of the states is not atomic.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I tried with a `time.sleep(3)` inbetween but it makes no difference.

Comment: using a `sleep` before polling running state changes the number. I got 1 before, now I get 5...

Comment: if you add some prints in call, you'll see that only 2 processes are running. The running state is probably not reliable.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre So you think that the `Future.running` method is broken?

Comment: no, it's just not returning the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would not trust this `running()` method too much. Seems that it's not really reflecting the actual running state.

The best way to make sure of the process states is to make them print/update something. I've chosen to create a shared dictionary using a `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()` object.

This process-synchronized object can be consulted/updated safely from any process and has a shared state, even in multiprocessing environment.

Each time a process is started, update the shared dict with the PID as key and `True` as a value. Set `False` on exit.

```
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing
import time,os


def call(shared_dict):
    shared_dict[os.getpid()] = True
    print("start",shared_dict)
    time.sleep(10)
    shared_dict[os.getpid()] = False
    print("end",shared_dict)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        shared_dict = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
        futures = [executor.submit(call,shared_dict) for _ in range(8)]
        time.sleep(5)
        for future in futures:
            print(future.running())
```

here's the output I'm getting:

```
start {3076: True}
start {9968: True, 3076: True}
True
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
end {9968: True, 3076: False}
start {9968: True, 3076: True}
end {9968: False, 3076: True}
start {9968: True, 3076: True}
end {9968: True, 3076: False}
start {9968: True, 3076: True}
end {9968: False, 3076: True}
start {9968: True, 3076: True}
end {9968: True, 3076: False}
start {9968: True, 3076: True}
end {9968: False, 3076: True}
start {9968: True, 3076: True}
end {9968: True, 3076: False}
end {9968: False, 3076: False}
```

As you can see, I have 5 running processes. Whereas my dictionary clearly shows that

- no more than 2 processes are running at the same time
- the processes are created just once at the start, then reused to execute further calls (it's a pool, after all)

Let's check the very minimalist [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.running):

> running()  Return True if the call is currently being executed and cannot be cancelled.

It seems to reflect a state related to a possibility of cancelling the `Future` object future execution (because it hasn't been initialized properly yet/connected to the communication queue and it's still time to cancel it) rather an actual "running" status of the process itself.

That's probably what this comment in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py) means below `set_running_or_notify_cancel` definition:

> Mark the future as running or process any cancel notifications.
>
> If the future has been cancelled (cancel() was called and returned True) then any threads waiting on the future completing (though calls to as_completed() or wait()) are notified and False is returned.
>
> **If the future was not cancelled then it is put in the running state (future calls to running() will return True) and True is returned.**

Once again, we learn that it's better to ask subprocesses to collaborate, publishing their status, rather than trying to extort it using unclearly documented methods.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code proving that only 2 calls are running. However to me it looks like a bug in the `Future.running` method implementation which returns inconsistent states. If you sleep for 5 seconds before checking the future statuses (like in your example), you are sure that all futures are in the pending state except 2 which should be in the running state. So the `Future.running` method should not return 3, 5, or any number different than 2. Otherwise why exposing such a useless method in the first place? I filed a bug in the Python Bug Tracker: https://bugs.python.org/issue37276.

Comment: I don't think it's useless. good call about the bug report. I'm interested in the results. The code is non-trivial to say the least.

Comment: I have found a nastier bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609847