# Why do ProcessPoolExecutor and Pool crash with a super() call?

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing, process-pool

**1. Why does the following Python code using the `concurrent.futures` module hang forever?**

```
import concurrent.futures


class A:

    def f(self):
        print("called")


class B(A):

    def f(self):
        executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
        executor.submit(super().f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    B().f()
```

The call raises an invisible exception `[Errno 24] Too many open files` (to see it, replace the line `executor.submit(super().f)` with `print(executor.submit(super().f).exception())`).

However, replacing `ProcessPoolExecutor` with `ThreadPoolExecutor` prints "called" as expected.

**2. Why does the following Python code using the `multiprocessing.pool` module raise the exception `AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children`?**

```
import multiprocessing.pool


class A:

    def f(self):
        print("called")


class B(A):

    def f(self):
        pool = multiprocessing.pool.Pool(2)
        pool.apply(super().f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    B().f()
```

However, replacing `Pool` with `ThreadPool` prints "called" as expected.

Environment: CPython 3.7, MacOS 10.14.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` and `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` uses `multiprocessing.queues.Queue` to pass the work function object from caller to worker process, `Queue` uses `pickle` module to serialize/unserialize, but it failed to proper processing bound method object with child class instance:

```py
f = super().f
print(f)
pf = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(f))
print(pf)
```

outputs:

```py
<bound method A.f of <__main__.B object at 0x104b24da0>>
<bound method B.f of <__main__.B object at 0x104cfab38>>
```

`A.f` becomes `B.f`, this effectly creates infinite recursive calling `B.f` to `B.f` in the worker process.

`pickle.dumps` utilize `__reduce__` method of bound method object, IMO, [its implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Objects/classobject.c#L75-L89), has no consideration of this scenario, which does not take care of the real `func` object, but only try to get back from instance `self` obj (`B()`) with the simple name (`f`), which resulting `B.f`, very likely a bug.

good news is, as we know where the issue is, we could fix it by implementing our own reduction function that tries to recreate the bound method object from the original function (`A.f`) and instance obj (`B()`):

```
import types
import copyreg
import multiprocessing

def my_reduce(obj):
    return (obj.__func__.__get__, (obj.__self__,))

copyreg.pickle(types.MethodType, my_reduce)
multiprocessing.reduction.register(types.MethodType, my_reduce)
```

we could do this because bound method is a descriptor.

ps: I have filed [a bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue37297).

Comment: One word: impressive!

Comment: There is an issue with the Python workaround `multiprocessing.reduction.register(types.MethodType, my_reduce)`: if you then try to instanciate a `multiprocessing.Manager()` you get this exception: `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function BaseManager._run_server at 0x00000198B0A91D90>: it's not the same object as multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager._run_server`. It seems to only affect Windows though.